# Login from popup Get data from profile

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup

I am trying to log into investing.com to go to my portfolio so I can get the current information on the page.
I am having an issue with the Login because it is not on the main page, but a popup page called "loginPopupform"

Here is my code that I have tried.

```
String baseUrl = "https://www.investing.com"; 
String sChartLink = "https://www.investing.com/portfolio";
String strLogin = "username";
String strPassword = "password" ;
String ua = "\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0\"";
Response res = null;
Document docRes = null;  
res = Jsoup
           .connect(baseUrl)
           .timeout(30000)
           .method(Connection.Method.POST)
           .data("loginFormUser_email", strLogin, "loginForm_password", strPassword)
           .userAgent(ua)
            .execute();        
docRes = res.parse();
Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();
doc1 = Jsoup.connect(sChartLink).userAgent(ua).cookies(cookies).get();
sDate = doc1.select("input[id=\"curDate\"]").text();
```

The sDate is empty and when I look into the doc1, there isn't any information that is in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

To make that you need to force the JS of the website because the pop-up modal is not static content so Jsoup does not retrieve it. So you need to use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) to force the JS and retrieve the dynamic content.

If it's a pop-up modal I guess you need to click on a button to load it, the way to do that using Selenium for Java is as it follows:

```
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)webDriver;

webDriver.get(URL);

WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 15); // wait 15 seconds

WebElement button = webDriver.findElement(By.id("id of the button that triggers the modal"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);

webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("loginPopupform")));

String fullHtml = webDriver.getPageSource();
```

Hope it helped you! Feel free to ask me anything else!

Comment: Thanks for the info ... There is so much on the Selenium link, what should I be downloading?

Comment: Also, looking at the web page, what you press is a link for an onclick.  Here is the entire <a> ... <a onclick="overlay.overlayLogin();" href="javascript:void(0);" class="login bold">Sign In</a>  What would I use for the button id?

Comment: @EddiRae check the Selenium docs or this post https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/selenium/selenium-tutorial-for-beginners/#toc500, what you need is to learn how to use the By selector. Basically you need to change By.id() to By + the css selector you want to look for, for example: By.className(), By.name(), By.id, etc. In this particular case you need to use: By.class("login bold") or By.class("login"). Hope it helped you! +1 the answer please!